# DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL not displaying complete DDL for big tables

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer

While generating the DDL for a schema, big tables' DDL are getting truncated. After displaying close to 110 rows I am getting an ellipsis (`...`).

I am using SQL developer to run:

```
SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE',TABLE_NAME,OWNER)
FROM DBA_TABLES
WHERE OWNER = 'XYZ'
```

Comment: If you click on the ellipses, does a window open that has the full contents of the CLOB?  Most GUIs won't try to display the full contents of a `LOB` since a single `LOB` could be multiple petabytes in length.

Comment: Hi justin, thanks for responding. In this case the ellipsis are non expanding. it's actually a text.

Answer (score 4):

Just set the "long" in the sql sheet window big enough to hold the desired ddl.

Example:

```
set long 1000
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'XP','OPS$RM74384') from dual;
```

-- Then just hit Run Script button or press f5.

Answer (score 1):

I tried running the script in TOAD and it generated the complete DDL. Not sure though why SQL Dev was not generating them.